# Hyperlinked Field Getting data from C#

Tags: asp.net

I would like to create a column of Hyperlinked Fields in my datagrid. However, in order to create the url for each link, i need a guid that was generated in the code behind. Is there any way to get hold of that value and use it in my datagrid control?

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure... utilize the OnItemDataBound in your DataGrid

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%"
    ShowHeader="false" OnItemDataBound="DataGridODB" BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None"
    CssClass="FormGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="MyHiperLynk1" runat="server" />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="MyHiperLynk2" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

And grab some databinder fields, and or generate your guid code

```
protected void DataGridODB(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        int LinkID = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "LinkID").ToString());
        Guid myGuid = new Guid();
        // populate your GUID code here
        ((HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("MyHiperLynk1")).NavigateUrl = String.Format("http://www.lmnop.qrs/default.aspx?id={0}&guid={1}", LinkID, myGuid);
        ((HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("MyHiperLynk2")).NavigateUrl = String.Format("http://www.lmnop.qrs/index.aspx?id={0}&guid={1}", LinkID, myGuid);
    }
}
```